# Sharing Docker cache across Docker-in-Docker containers

Tags: docker, docker-registry, docker-in-docker

I would like to share the docker image cache across several Docker-in-Docker containers running on the same host.

I realise that the DIND setup is not ideal, but at the moment I'm trying to minimise changes in a tricky setup.

Is there a way I can expose the host's Docker cache to the DIND containers running on it? Or another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see this working through mounting `/var/lib/docker` or (preferably, I think) `/var/lib/docker/image` in the container, either directly there or changing the daemon's `data-root`. That would definitely depending on using the same driver both in the container and on the host. It might also eat your babies though.

As a side note, do you really need to actively build images that share things both on the container and the host, though? I feel like in most DIND scenarios, you'd prefer building images mostly inside the container...

Comment: Leonardo, have you an example to mount /var/lib/docker ?? 

I have problems: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64278170/how-to-enable-persistent-volumes-on-kubernetes-for-docker-in-docker

Comment: I don't, never did DIND myself. I think just sharing `/var/lib/docker` will probably give you problems at some point.