# How to enable persistent volumes on Kubernetes for docker in docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-in-docker

to speed up docker build on kubernetes, I want to enable persistent volumes
I tried this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: docker-build
spec:
  volumes:
  - name: dind-storage
    # emptyDir: {}                    # that's how it works
    persistentVolumeClaim:            # so it doesn't work
      claimName: "jenkinslibdocker"    
  containers:
  - name: docker
    image: docker:19.03.3-git
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
    env:
    - name: DOCKER_HOST
      value: tcp://localhost:2375
  - name: dind
    image: docker:19.03.3-dind
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
    env:
    - name: DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR
      value: ''
    args:
    - "--mtu=1440"
    volumeMounts:
      - name: dind-storage
        mountPath: /var/lib/docker
```

I create the pod:

```
kubectl create -f test2.yaml
```

and the pvc:

```
kubectl create -f pvc.yaml



apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: jenkinslibdocker
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
  storageClassName: nfs-client
  volumeMode: Filesystem
```

Enter in the pod:

```
kubectl exec -it docker-build -c docker sh
```

Try to build anything

```
docker build https://github.com/liejuntao001/docker_doxygen.git --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 --tag baibai/doxygen:latest --cache-from baibai/doxygen:latest
```

i get the error:
failed to register layer: operation not supported

If I disable the persistent volume, it works

Some idea ?

Comment: Have you created the PVC `jenkinslibdocker`? Add the YAML of PVC too.

Comment: Yes, I updated the question, inserting the pvc code

Comment: What `nfs-client` are you using for the PV?

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes-retired/external-storage/tree/master/nfs-client

Comment: I'm sorry to comment on an old question but I'm facing the same problem. Did you solve it?